# Is there any method for vm update in azure except update management tool in automation account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I need to develop powershell script for automating vm patches updating in azure. I know we can do it by using azure update management but is there any other way to do it? I'm new to it please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to this [Virtual Machines - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/update) to update a virtual machine.

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2020-06-01
```

In addition, we could also do this in the UI and capture the request URL and request Body in the Network via F12, then convert it to power shell script.

Comment: I need to update vm at a specified time with powershell script so can you help me in that with a bit details

Comment: You could do this in the azure portal right? Click F12->Network and do it again, then we could capture the request body and url. You could check it and share the result here.

Comment: Hi @KrushnaKumar, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/34045/i-want-to-prepareing-powershell-script-to-update-o.html) Microsoft Q&A platform question, you may use PSWindowsUpdate powershell module cmdlets.

And, if you are looking for a way to implement a way by removing dependency on Azure Automation and Azure Log Analytics then check [Automatic VM guest patching (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/automatic-vm-guest-patching).

Also, I would love to know the reason for trying to manually develop script for automating VM patches when the same is already available to us in the form of [Update management solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/overview) (that is integrated with Azure Automation and Azure Log Analytics).